# Eagle: Circular area under component colliding with traces

Tags: pcb, usb, eaglecad, layout

I am creating a PCB layout in Eagle and I noticed that when I add in the ground plane, there are two unfilled circular areas under the usb mini type B socket.  Does that area need to be empty?

I have some traces going under the USB socket, is it okay if I leave them there?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You cannot leave traces under a hole

Comment: Oh thanks!  I didn't realize it was a physical hole. I thought it was just a hole in the ground plane.

Comment: Have you haven physically verified the connector against the footprint? The connector needs two holes AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - two holes are needed.  Thanks for the reminder